# How to fix Exe file only running on one computer

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I have created a basic screen on pygame, and want to compile it to send to a friend as a test, and the file runs perfectly on my computer

However, on my friends computer, it does not run.

He has no versions of python or pygame on their computer, and I am using a Pycharm Project interpreter with just pygame and cx_Freeze installed

**Game code**

```
import sys, pygame

size = 600, 600
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

colour = (70, 70, 70)

while 1:

    screen.fill(colour)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

**Build file**

```
import cx_Freeze
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\jls45\Documents\Curse\code\BigBossBattleGame\venv\Scripts\tcl86t.dll'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\jls45\Documents\Curse\code\BigBossBattleGame\venv\Scripts\tk86t.dll'

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("Main.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Test",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"],
                           "include_files":["test.png"]}},
    executables = executables
)
```

Comment: Change the absolute paths to relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Since your friend doesn't have Python or pygame, they probably also don't have tk/tcl.  You'll need to package those .dll's with your executable.

```
"include_files":[
    "test.png",
    r'C:\Users\jls45\Documents\Curse\code\BigBossBattleGame\venv\Scripts\tcl86t.dll',
    r'C:\Users\jls45\Documents\Curse\code\BigBossBattleGame\venv\Scripts\tk86t.dll',
]
```